# DB query to relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

**My query:**

```
$data = DB::table('countries')
        ->leftJoin('matches', function ($join) {
            $join->on('matches.hometeam', '=', 'countries.id')
            ->orOn('matches.awayteam', '=' ,'countries.id');
        })
        ->where('countries.id', $id)->get();

        return dd($data);
```

How can I get same results using relationship?

Comment: hasMany only works using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent). You are using the raw query builder.

Comment: you problem es in `join` pls edit and post you table

Answer (score 1):

In your Model (You need a matches model aswell):

```php
<?php
class Country extends Model {
  public function matches() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Matches::class, ['hometeam', 'awayteam'], 'id');
  }
}
```

In your controller:

```php
$countrys = Countrys::where('id', $id)->get()
foreach($countrys as $country) {
  var_dump($country->matches);
}
die();
```

Comment: You'll only have home games though.

Comment: @AOWulinGuide I dont undestand your argument - you don't have do access the matches object...

Comment: @Devon yes, but you can also add more and more relations, and i will also select only games with the qualified id, no matter if they actually have the relation or not.

Comment: anyway to get 
`
  public function matchesHome() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Matches::class, 'hometeam', 'id');
  }
  public function matchesAway() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Matches::class, 'awayteam', 'id');
  }
`
in one function

Comment: @Insax i try ur updated code and error  Array to string conversion